# MEAN Stack using Docker containers

Tags: node.js, angular, express, docker, mean-stack

New to this...

I'm trying to understand if a modern MEAN app should be deployed with 3 or 2 Docker containers:

**Option 1:** Express Server as container + Mongo DB as container

**Option 2:** All three as separate Docker containers

The second option sounds like the appropriate path so you can update any part of the stack without taking down other components if you don't want to. But then the question is does the ng app container need it's own server to serve the ng app files. I'm seeing some examples on Github where they are running the ng app with `ng serve -H 0.0.0.0` from the Docker container which from my understanding is a *no-no* because that's not a prod ready server, just webpacks dev server.

To me, if you run all three separately then you actually need two servers, one to server the ng app (index.html, js, css, etc.) and the other to sever the backend app, the API.

The advantage I see if you run the Express Sever + ng app in one container then you can serve the initial `index.html` with ng app dependencies AND the API but then they both go down when they get updated.

What's the best practice here?

Comment: not sure what the down vote was for...

Comment: This is actually a good question in my opinion.

Comment: I suppose it could be considered MEEAN in the context of deploying with 3 separate containers because the ng app would require an additional sever.  ;) For Docker deployment.

Comment: lol yea. Of course you don't necessarily need to use Express to serve your angular files but it could be faster since you already know it. Either way, you may also wanna look into something like nginx or apache if you're thinking production. I think docker has an official nginx container

Answer (score 2):

IMHO 2 Containers seems like the better solution with one for Mongo and one for Express. Anytime you're pushing new code, it doesn't make sense to have a front end still up if back end is down or vice versa. Also serving front end files from the same server reduces headaches of dealing with CSRF.

Regarding your other question, I think you can deploy your front end to something like AWS S3 and still only manage one server for your backend.

on a side note, you could also do it all in one container. It really depends on your other requirements to figure out the best architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the note @arash. Just to make a case for separate containers, the situation could be that other apps are using the same Express API (say mobile app) so you could say just update the ng app and not break the other apps.

Comment: But I agree, it seems like you would reduce headaches when dealing with CSRF / CORS.

Comment: There you go! That's what I meant by your other requirements :) Yes, if your backend apis are being used by multiple front-ends / mobile apps then you definitely wanna separate them.